# Algorithm errors and bad math environment delimiter

Tags: math-mode, formatting, algorithms

I'm struggling a lot in writing the pseudo-codes in latex. Please review below two algorithms. In the document, the algorithms do look good apart from the highlighted part in the picture.

[image]

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Incident Description and Text Separation}
\label{algo:1}
\KwIn{Text file T of all the Incidents}
\KwOut{Short description and Updates of each Incident as a .CSV fIle \(c\).}
split T if line in T begins with `Incident:'\\
\For{\textup{each split of} \(e\) in T}
{
     Short description \Leftarrow \( \) Line starting with 'short\textunderscore description:'\\
     Updates \Leftarrow \( \) Line starting with 'sys\textunderscore mod\textunderscore count:'\\
}
\end{algorithm}
```

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Preprocessing the description field of each incident   \(i\)}
\label{algo:2}
\KwIn{Short description of each incident \(i\)}
\KwOut{Preprocessed short descriptions to single strings.}
convert description of each incident \(i\) to lowercase\\
stopwords \Leftarrow \( \) repeatedly occurring words and person names\\
\For{\textup{each incident} i}
{
  \If{\textup{\textit{word }in short description} \in stopwords}{\textup{replace \(word\) with nothing}}
  \endIf
\textup{remove all special symbols \& characters}\\
\textup{remove all extra line \& word spaces}\\
}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: (Not tested.)  I'd be inclined to move the last `\\ ` in the second algorithm outside of the closing brace that ends the internal "if" component.

Comment: @barbara_beeton: Still looking the same did not work :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could  you  post a *full compilable* code, not just a snippet?

Comment: @Bernand: What do you mean by full compilable code? I did not understand.

Comment: @kauflandholland Start from `\documentclass{...}` with your packages used (`\usepackage{....}`) + `\begin{document}` (your text)`\end{document}`.

Comment: As @Sebastiano says…

Comment: The problem is that you are missing `$ $` for math symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using `algorithm2e` to insert algorithms.

Also, you have to insert math symbols in math mode, eg, `$\Leftarrow$`.

Finally, delete the `Endif`.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Preprocessing the description field of each incident $i$}
\label{algo:2}
\KwIn{Short description of each incident $i$.}
\KwOut{Preprocessed short descriptions to single strings.}
convert description of each incident $i$ to lowercase\\
stopwords $\Leftarrow$ repeatedly occurring words and person names\\
\For{\textup{each incident} $i$}
{
  \If{\textup{\textit{word} in short description $\in$ \textit{stopwords}}}{\textup{replace \textit{word} with nothing}}
  \textup{remove all special symbols \& characters}\\
  \textup{remove all extra line \& word spaces}\\
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, it isn't necessary to explicitly call for the latter.

Comment: Thank you all :)